# Spring-XD: Deployment of modules to certain containers

Tags: spring-xd

Three questions regarding deployment of modules to Spring XD container:

1. For certain sources and sinks it's necessary to say to which container a module should be deployed. Let's say we have a lot of containers on different machines, and we want to establish a stream reading a log file from one machine. The source module of type tail has to be deployed to the container running on the machine with the log file. How can you do that?
2. You may want to restrict the execution of modules to a group of containers. Let's say we have some powerful machines for our batch processing with containers on it, and we have other machines where our container runs parallel to some other processes only for ingesting data (log files etc.). Is that possible?
3. If we have a custom module, is it possible to add the module xml and the jars just to certain containers, so that those modules are just executed there? Or is it necessary that we have the same module definitions on all containers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You bring up excellent points, we have been doing some design work around these issues, in particular #1 and #2 and will have some functionality here in our next milestone release in about 1 month time.

In terms of #3, the model for resolving the jars that are loaded in the containers requires the local file system or a shared file system to resolve the classpath.  This is also something that has come up in our prototypes of using Spring XD on the CloudFoundry PaaS and we want to provide a more dynamic/at runtime ability to located and load new modules.  No estimate on when that will be address.

Thanks for questions!

Cheers,
Mark